# 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found React Native 0.71.5 Intel Macbook

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I am working on a project with `react-native@0.71.5`.  I have an Intel MacBook. After the pod was installed I got error above error.

**My Podfile**

````
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

abstract_target 'LeafEm' do

# React Native Maps dependencies
# The following line is only needed if building on an Apple silicon Mac without rosetta.
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', :git => 'https://github.com/Simon-TechForm/google-maps-ios-utils.git', :branch => 'feat/support-apple-silicon'

rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path

  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'LeafEmTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'LeafEm Dev' do
  end
  
  target 'LeafEm Test' do
  end
  
  target 'LeafEm UAT' do
  end
  
  target 'LeafEm Stage' do
  end
  
  target 'LeafEm Prod' do
  end
  
  
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
````

Got the error

```
'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Install rosetta on mac, and use rosetta simualtors.